# how to prevent mysql from createing mysql-bin.00000x files?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mysqlbinlog

I see that mysql creates a lot of files that are named like mysql-bin.000001, mysql-bin.000002, mysql-bin.000003 etc.
I've found [here](http://qnalist.com/questions/4184346/mysql-bin-00000x) that my log_bin setting is "ON".
I'm wondering how I can set this to off and if that's a smart thing to do.
I've tried this: `set log_bin = "OFF";` but it resulted to this: `ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_bin' is a read only variable`

On multiple websites I've found [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-mysql-binary-log/) solution and changed it in "/etc/my.cnf":

> Disable MySQL binlogging
>
> If you are not replicating, you can disable binlogging by changing
>   your my.ini or my.cnf file. Open your my.ini or /etc/my.cnf
>   (/etc/mysql/my.cnf), enter:
>
> `# vi /etc/my.cnf`
>
> Find a line that reads "log_bin" and remove or comment it as follows:
>
> `# log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log`
>
> You also need to remove or comment following lines:
>
> `# expire_logs_days        = 10`
>
> `# max_binlog_size         = 100M`
>
> Close and save the file.
>
> Finally, restart mysql server:
>
> `# service mysql restart`

But this doesn't seem to have any affect at all.
As far as I could find, these files mainly exist for replication, but I'm not replicating anything.

Comment: the binary logs can also be used in case of disaster recovery, but mysql can run fine with them turned off

Comment: Thanks @pala_, but how do I turn it off?

Comment: just comment out `log_bin = ...` so it looks like `# log_bin = ...`

Comment: log_bin wasn't even in my file, but I did add it, with a # in front of it.

Comment: i suppose it could also be turned on as part of the startup script.. let me know if it fixes it

Comment: The part about having to comment out two more lines is not correct. Try the MySQL manual, not arbitrary Interet junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that there was a setting `server-id=1` that I had to remove. Problem is solved now.

Comment: Hello, sorry to ressurect old topic. Did you remove the whole line all together or just comment out? I'm having similar issue 200+ GB per day, commented out log_bin, didn't fix.

Comment: I removed the line, I didn't need it so there was no need to comment it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the binary logging (necessary for replication, useful for recovery), do it by commenting out the `log_bin = ...` line in your my.cnf, and restarting the server. mysql will run fine without it.

You can manually view the binary logs within mysql by executing `show binary logs`, and you can get rid of them with the `purge binary logs` command, if you want to leave it active and deal with them from time to time.